# selection only works for the first Text node in a TextFlow

Tags: javafx, input, selection

I currently have a TextFlow, putting Text Nodes and other types of nodes into it, I'm trying to make the text selectable using mouse and key events, but the methods **setSelectionStart** and **setSelectionEnd** don't seem to behave the way they should, like it works fine for the first Text node but not for others

Here is a minimal reproducible example :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage ps) {
    TextFlow flow = new TextFlow();
    flow.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    
    Text t1 = new TextNode("first ");
    Text t2 = new TextNode("second ");
    Text t3 = new TextNode("third");
    
    t1.setSelectionStart(2);
    t1.setSelectionEnd(6);
    t2.setSelectionStart(0);
    t2.setSelectionEnd(4);
    
    flow.getChildren().addAll(t1, t2, t3);
    
    ps.setScene(new Scene(flow,400,300));
    ps.show();
}

private class TextNode extends Text {
    public TextNode(String s) {
        super(s);
        setFont(Font.font(18));
        setSelectionFill(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

I'm basically creating a TextFlow and inserting 3 Text nodes into it, i want to be able to make a selection across the first and second Text nodes, but it's not working, see the screenshot below

[image: screenshot]

The [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) indicate that

> When a Text node is inside of a TextFlow, some of its properties are ignored

But I don't seem to find the correct approach to make a continuous selection across Text nodes, note that i can't join them in a single Text node because there could be a non-text node between them, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: not supported - see the duplicate for options (and a reference to an open issue)

Comment: the answer on that question says that Text is not selectable, but the Text node has functions to set the selection start and end, and it works for a single Text node (changes the color of the selected range to the selectionFill property), it seems like the Textflow is overriding some of that behaviour in a way that is not documented anywhere and that i don't understand.

Comment: what don't you understand? it's simply not supported - you have to do it yourself (don't know how simple/complex that would be). Do a bit of research, read the sources, maybe somebody has implemented something useful.

Comment: totally understandable, thank you for your help